# onDraw not being called to ImageViews that are inside ViewPager

Tags: android, ondraw

I have a ViewPager of ImageViews, and I overrided the `onDraw(..)` of the ImageViews so that I draw stuff on top of the imageview. Throughout the run of the app I change these drawings so I manually call `invalidate()` to make `onDraw()` get called (and thus updating the drawings).

The weird thing is, the only `onDraw()` that is called is for the first ImageView and not the others. (Meaning only to the ImageView that is displayed first. After scrolling to the next ImageView, `onDraw()` stops being called)

I've called `setWillNotDraw(false)` in the constructor of the ImageView.

Did anyone have the same experience? Why is this happening?

Comment: after scrolling do you see anything on the other `ImageView`s?

Comment: (sorry for not mention it earlier) - I see the drawings on the next ImageView

Comment: so `onDraw` is called as it is the normal method where any `View`s draw themselve

Comment: It is called only after scrolling to the next ImageView, not right away! I've added a Tag for the current image view and retrieved it using 'findViewByTag' and then called 'invalidate()', but only after scrolling the 'onDraw()' gets called!

Comment: ok what happens if you comment out `onDraw` method in your custom `ImageView`?

Comment: `onDraw` contains the logic that draws on top of the canvas. After commenting it out, the drawing stopped. I put a `Log` statement there, and it is still being called only when scrolling

Answer (score 0):

One reason that the onDraw method may not be called for an ImageView is if you haven't set the image resource (i.e. ImageView  src parameter)  If you're setting it programmatically that would be done by a call to setImageResource. Make sure you're specifying the image resource properly and that the resource exists.

I discovered this issue making a custom control for displaying animated GIFs.  For sdk < version 28, I used android.graphic.Movie to accomplish this, and for sdk >= version 28, I an using the new ImageDecode. In order to accomplish that my custom control had to be extended from ImageView.   When I did that, my onDraw method no longer got called.  The problem went away when I set the image resource.  In the case when I using Movie to render the GIF, I'm not really using the ImageView for doing the rendering, but I still had to give Image view a dummy image resource just so I get a call to the onDraw method.  The use of Invalidate and SetWillNotDraw(false) methods will not solve this kind of problem.